# Set of actions before enabling submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my form to meet a set of criterias before the submit button gets enabled, my form is in this order:

1. Text field, value has to be over 150
2. Set of radio selects, 1 has to be selected
3. TOS box, has to be checked

So far I have this:

```
if ((parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10) > 149) && $('input:radio[name="radioset1"]').is(':checked') && ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')))
{ 

// Enable Button here

 }
```

Do I have to add this to everything I'm checking, for example keyup on the textfield, change on the select and checkbox and set true in variables that those fields are "OK" or how do I do it ?

Comment: why don't you enable disable button in your validation logics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom validate function, which you have to run onchange of your text field, and on click of your radio and checkbox click event.
Following psudo code might help you.

```
var textFieldValidationPassed = false;

function validateFormFields() {
  //First checks if text field length is not less then 150.
  // then check if one of the radio button is selected.
  // then check for TOS box checked state;
  if (textFieldValidationPassed && $('input:radio[name="radioset1"]').is(':checked') && ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')))
    // enable submit button;
   }
}
$('input:radio[name="radioset1"]', 'input.checkbox_check').click(function() {
  validateFormFields();  
})
$('#amount').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().length > 149) {
    textFieldValidationPassed =true;
    validateFormFields(); 
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

it is a workaround but will work, make submit button initially...

```
$(":submit").on('focus',Validate);



function Validate(){
    if ((parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10) > 149) && $('input:radio[name="radioset1"]').is(':checked') && ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')))
    { 

    // Enable Button here

     }
    else
    {
        //Disable button
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add click, change events at once like this

```
$("input").on("change, click", function(){

});
```

Write your logic within this.

Also you've checkbox validation wrong. Check box will be clicked.

```
$('input.checkbox_check').prop('checked')
```

Here is the complete code

```
$(function(){
    $("input").on("change, click", function(){
        if ((parseInt($('#UserName').val(), 10) > 149) && $('input:radio[name="gender"]').is(':checked') && $("#remember").prop('checked'))
        { 
            $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else{
            $("#submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b3TvN/)**

Answer (score -1):

You can call it at textbox, radiobutton and checkbox onchange events.

**EDIT:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input").change(function () {
            //call function.
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery.validate. You can define custom validation methods too.

http://jqueryvalidation.org

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTML5 validation. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" required name="checkbox1" />
<input type="text" min="150" name="input1" />
```

You can see another example here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_attributes.asp